# Matrix dimnames different from sequence of values

Tags: r

I have this code to create a matrix:

```
TTCm <- seq(from=-4, to=0, by=0.1)
Speedm <- seq(from=15, to=25, by=0.5)
matrix2 <- matrix(nrow = 41, ncol = 21)
dimnames(matrix2) = list(TTCm, Speedm)
```

However (depending on the sequence) dimnames might give weird values. In the above particular case TTCm -0.1 is -0.0999999999999996.
Does anyone know what the problem here is? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because computer uses finite precision arithmetic. it's well known as "floating point problem". so the 40th value of TTcm you can see on R console is a approximate value. you can check it by using dplyr::near() on R console. Try the code below.

`TTCm <- seq(from=-4, to=0, by=0.1)
TTCM[40] == -0.1
dplyr::near(TTCm[40], -0.1)`

if you don't understand completely, Try the code below. Maybe you can totally understand.

`sqrt(2) ^ 2 == 2
1/10 * 10 == 1
near(sqrt(2)^2, 2)
near(1/10*10, 1)`

you need to be careful when handling floating point.

Comment: And what would be the easiest way to get around this? thanks

Comment: in the case, the easiest way is.. Try it like this.                     `dimnames(matrix2) =list(round(TTCm,10), Speedm)` I don't know this is the answer you wanted..